# limsup of events, and events of limsup of a sequence of random variables

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, limsup-and-liminf

Given a sequence of nonnegative random variables $\{Z_{n}\}$, for each
positive integer $k$, is it true that
$$
\left\{  \limsup_{n\to\infty}Z_{n} > \frac{1}{k}\right\}  =\limsup
_{n\to\infty}\left\{  Z_{n}>\frac{1}{k}\right\}
$$

[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit#Almost_sure_convergence): Let $Z_{n}=\left\vert Y_{n}-Y\right\vert $, since $\limsup_{n\to
\infty}Z_{n}\geq0$, the sets $\{\limsup_{n\to\infty}Z_{n}=0\}$ and
$\{\limsup_{n\to\infty}Z_{n}>0\}=\left\{  \limsup_{n\to\infty
}Z_{n}\neq0\right\}  $ form a partition of the sample space. We have
$$
\left\{  \limsup_{n\to\infty}Z_{n}>0\right\}  =\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty
}\left\{  \limsup_{n\to\infty}Z_{n}>\frac{1}{k}\right\}
=\lim_{k\to\infty}\left\{  \limsup_{n\to\infty}Z_{n}>\frac
{1}{k}\right\}
$$
However, [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit#Almost_sure_convergence)
gives $\lim_{k\to\infty}\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left\{
Z_{n}>\frac{1}{k}\right\}  $.

Comment: Let $Z_{m}=\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{m}$, then $\left\{
\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}Z_{n}>\frac{1}{k}\right\}  =\left\{  \frac{1}
{k}>\frac{1}{k}\right\}  =\emptyset$. However, $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty
}\left\{  Z_{n}>\frac{1}{k}\right\}  =\mathsf{\Omega}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will show that
$$
\mathsf{E}=\left\{  \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}Z_{n}>\frac{1}{k}\right\}
\subset\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left\{  Z_{n}>\frac{1}{k}\right\}
=\mathsf{F}
$$

First, $w\in\mathsf{E}\implies w\in\mathsf{F}$. Let $T_{n}(w)=\sup_{m\geq
n}Z_{m}(w)$ and
$$
V(w)=\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}Z_{n}(w)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sup_{m\geq
n}Z_{m}(w)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}T_{n}(w)
$$
If $w\in\mathsf{E}$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}T_{n}(w)=V(w)>\frac{1}{k}
$. Since $T_{n}\geq T_{n+1}$, we have $T_{n}(w)>\frac{1}{k}$ for all $n$. We
find that $w\in\bigcup_{m=n}^{\infty}\left\{  Z_{m}>\frac{1}{k}\right\}  $ for
all $n$. Otherwise, if $w\notin\bigcup_{m=n}^{\infty}\left\{  Z_{m}>\frac
{1}{k}\right\}  $ for some $n$, there must be $Z_{m}\leq\frac{1}{k}$ for all
$m\geq n$, which results in a contradiction $\frac{1}{k}<T_{n}=\sup_{m\geq
n}Z_{m}\leq\frac{1}{k}$. Thus, $w\in\mathsf{F}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty
}\bigcup_{m=n}^{\infty}\left\{  Z_{m}>\frac{1}{k}\right\}  $.

Second, there is $w\in\mathsf{F}$ but $w\notin\mathsf{E}$. For example, let
$X$ be a random variable with $0<X\leq1$, and $Z_{n}=\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{n}
X$, then $Z_{n}>\frac{1}{k}$ for all $n$, and $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty
}Z_{n}=\frac{1}{k}$. Thus, if $w\in X^{-1}((0,1])$, $w\in\mathsf{F}
=\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left\{  Z_{n}>\frac{1}{k}\right\}  $ but
$w\notin\mathsf{E}=\left\{  \frac{1}{k}>\frac{1}{k}\right\}  =\emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

With "$>$", the inclusion only goes one way. A set of the form $\{\limsup_{n\to\infty} Z_n > a\}$ for $a > 0$ is **contained in, but not necessarily equal to**  $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\{Z_n>a\}$. To see this, if $\omega\in\{\limsup_{n\to\infty}Z_n>a\}$, then $Z_n(\omega)>a$ for infinitely many $n$, which is precisely what it means for $\omega\in \limsup_{n\to\infty}\{Z_n>a\}$.

The reverse membership does not hold, since if $Z_n > a$ for infinitely many $n$, all we may conclude is that $\limsup Z_n \ge a$. The counterexample in the other answer shows we may have strict containment.